# Bare metal programming in C for Raspberry pi

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, hardware

I am currently programming raspberry pi.

I wanted to get clear out some doubts, please can anybody help.

Here is the code snippet.

```
#define GPIO_BASE 0x20200000UL

gpio = (unsigned int*)GPIO_BASE; gpio[GPIO_GPFSEL1] |= (1 << 18);
```

This code is from http://www.valvers.com/embedded-linux/raspberry-pi/step01-bare-metal-programming-in-cpt1

I do understand the functionality of the code to switch on and switch off the LED .

I have problem understand the these statements

```
gpio = (unsigned int*)GPIO_BASE; gpio[GPIO_GPFSEL1] |= (1 << 18);
```

Comment: There is a pretty good youtube tutorial on bare metal programming for raspberry pi, it may help you some if you are having problems understanding this:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd9AVmcRc6U&list=PLVxiWMqQvhg9FCteL7I0aohj1_YiUx1x8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well ...

The first statement:

```
gpio = (unsigned int*)GPIO_BASE;
```

sets the pointer variable `gpio` equal to the value of `GPIO_BASE`, and also casts the latter to a pointer type.

The second

```
gpio[GPIO_GPFSEL1] |= (1 << 18);
```

does a bitwise OR of the value in `gpio[GPIO_GPFSEL1]` with the constant value `1 << 18`. This "turns on" bit 18 (counting from 0) in the register `GPIO_GPFSEL1`.

Remember that in C, array indexing `a[b]` is the same as `*(a + b)`, i.e. it's a pointer addition and dereferencing.

Answer (score 2):

First you have some address in memory.

```
define GPIO_BASE 0x20200000UL
```

Under this address exists a control structure for GPIO. In your case it's just an array of ints. Writing a value to a certain field of that structure makes GPIO set its pins.

```
gpio = (unsigned int*)GPIO_BASE;
```

You select some register in your structure (the address (unsigned int*)GPIO_BASE + GPIO_GPFSEL1) and you set the 18th bit on.

```
gpio[GPIO_GPFSEL1] |= (1 < < 18);
```

The GPIO will likely respond with setting one of its pins to high state. The LED attached to that pin will start glowing.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
gpio = (unsigned int*)GPIO_BASE;
```

gpio points to `0x20200000` memory address. This is "The base address of the GPIO peripheral (ARM Physical Address)".

Article that you've linked says that:

> Back to the processor manual and we see that the first thing we need
>   to do is set the GPIO pin to an output. This is done by setting the
>   function of GPIO16 to an output. Bits 18 to 20 in the ‘GPIO Function
>   Select 1′ register control the GPIO16 pin.

Statement

```
#define GPIO_GPFSEL1    1
gpio[GPIO_GPFSEL1] |= (1 << 18);
```

breaks down to:

```
gpio[1] = gpio[1] | (1 << 18);
```

So, address `(0x20200000 + sizeof(unsigned int))` is dereferenced and OR operator sets the bit 18 to 1.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the array part...that helpled !